# Getting ID value when clicking on listview

Tags: android, listview, sugarorm

I'm having some trouble getting the correct id value when clicking on the listview.

I made a custom adapter since I'm drawing from SQLite data, I get the right text back but when I click on a row, I get a 0 index id back, which is not what I want.

I'm also using Sugar ORM, so I'm not sure if that requires some special work from me to get the id field.

I'm not sure what I should show you in terms of code, so whatever you think will help you, let me know and I'll post it.

Thanks

```
BoardArrayAdapter adapter = new BoardArrayAdapter(this, boards);
setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView lv = getListView();

registerForContextMenu(lv);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Board ID " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Put code of `OnItemClickListener` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the `getItemId()` method in your adapter.
According to the SugarORM docs you can call `getid()`to return the db id.

```
ArrayList<Object> data;

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return data.get(position).getid();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am using on my project (with SQLite and CustomListView).

**getData method**

```
public void getData(View view, long id)
{
    //storing the ID into a public static variable and converting to int
    CLIENTE_ID = (int)id;

    //When the user touches on the field in the listview, I get the touched field's name and email
    TextView textViewnome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cliente_nome);
    TextView textViewemail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_cliente_email);

    //Stores both name and email of the touched field
    String nome = textViewnome.getText().toString();
    String email = textViewemail.getText().toString();

    //store into static variable
    CLIENTE_NOME = nome;
    CLIENTE_EMAIL = email;
}
```

**within onCreate:**

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            getData(view, id);
            Log.d("myClass", "ID: " + view.getId());
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps! :)